# Tingle sensation while reading Quran after prayer

Tags: reading-quran

I prayed 2 Rakat and then read some Quran. I got a tingle sensation throughout my body while reading Quran. I also felt like crying after I was done some reading. It is Shan-e-Barat. Is this good?

Answer (score 0):

No this is a good sign. Let me read you a Hadith:

«إِنَّ لِلْقُلُوبِ إِقْبَالاً وَ إِدْبَاراً فَإِذَا أَقْبَلَتْ فَاحْمِلُوهَا عَلَی النَّوَافِلِ وَ إِذَا أَدْبَرَتْ فَاقْتَصِرُوا بِهَا عَلَی الْفَرَائِضِ»
312. Amir al-mu'minin, peace be upon him, said: Sometimes the hearts move forward and sometimes they move backward. When they move forward get them to perform the optionals (as well), but when they move backward keep them confined to obligatories only. Nahjul Balagha, Hadith n: 312

The reason you cry is that your heart has made a strong connection to Allah and the Quran has affected your soul as we read in the Quran:

Say, ‘Whether you believe in it, or do not believe in it, indeed those who were given knowledge before it when it is recited to them, fall down in prostration on their faces, Say, ‘Whether you believe in it, or do not believe in it, indeed those who were given knowledge before it when it is recited to them, fall down in prostration on their faces, Weeping, they fall down on their faces, and it increases them in humility.’

Allah loves the crying eye, who cries in supplication and LOVE toward Him, who cries out of Love to the Messenger of Allah Muhammad PBUH and the ones Allah loves

just keep on reciting Quran and don't feel blame to cry out